# Check if all child elements have display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to determine whether or not all child divs of `#container` have `display:none` on them. [I can't use `:visible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222853/use-jquery-to-check-if-all-divs-are-hidden/1222886) because `container` itself is a panel that is hidden, and can be opened (makes it visible) and closed (hides it again).

The goal is to remove the "click to open the container panel" text when the panel is completely empty, and show it again when at least one child div is shown.

The different child divs are shown and closed in other parts of my code, independently.

I've tried:

```
function check_if_all_divs_are_hidden()
{
    if($('#container').children().css('display') == 'none') {
      //hide text
    }
    else
    {
      //show text
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work, because if one div has the  `display:none` property, it will hide the text, while it should only hide the text when all divs have this property.

Comment: Check the length of total child div's and those having display none property. If they are same, hide the text.

Comment: Give them a class. Set the class when hidden, count the children with that class

Comment: @Abinthaha: how do I combine `css('display') == 'none'` with `.length`?

Comment: You cannot simply do it in a single line. You need to loop through child's and get the number of childs having display none proprty. But by es6 methods like `.find`, `.map` etc. this can be done in a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I altered [minitauros' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841122/955823) a bit, and got a working solution:

```
function check_if_all_are_hidden()
{
    all_are_hidden = true;
    $("#container").children().each(function(){
        if($(this).css('display') !== 'none')
        {
            all_are_hidden = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (all_are_hidden) {
        console.log("all hidden");
    } else {
        console.log("some are open");
    }
}
```

Will mark this as the correct answer in 2 days, unless someone finds a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Check this.

```js
$('.check-btn').on('click', function() {
  if($('.item').length === $('.hidden').length)   {
    //hide text
    console.log('same');
  } else {
    //Show Text
    console.log('different');
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;'
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#container'>
  <span class='item hidden'>1</span>
  <span class='item hidden'>2</span>
  <span class='item hidden'>3</span>
  <span class='item'>4</span>
  <span class='item hidden'>5</span>
  <span class='item hidden'>6</span>
</div>

<button class='check-btn'>Check</button>
```

Comment: @binoculars: Is this working according to your expectation?

Comment: Good suggestion! I was hoping for a solution without the need to alter all my classes, though. Upvoted.

Comment: You can do the same without altering the classes. If you want, i can post a solution

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).next('.content').hasClass('active')){
      $(this).text('Show');
      $(this).next('.content').removeClass('active');
    }else{
      $(this).text('Hide');
      $(this).next('.content').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
  display:none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#container'>
  <span class='item'>1</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="content">Some 1</div>
  <hr>
  <span class='item'>2</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="content">Some 2</div>
  <hr>
  <span class='item'>3</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="content">Some 3</div>
</div>
```

You can use also something like this :D

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
function check_if_all_divs_are_hidden() {
  let all_are_hidden = true;

  $('#container').children().each(child => {
    if ($(child).css('display') !== 'hidden') {
      all_are_hidden = false;
      return false; // Break as we've found one child that isn't hidden, which means not all are hidden.
    }
  });

  if (all_are_hidden) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: This give me an error: `child.css is not a function`

Comment: My bad, I think it ought to be `$(child).css`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
function check_if_all_divs_are_hidden()
{
    // Hide text
    $('#container').children().each((idx,elt)=>{
        if($(elt).children().css('display') != 'none') {
           //show text
        }
    })
}
```

That way it will hide the text if all child are hidden and show it if at least one is visible

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know, i'll dig more into my code to find what went wrong =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to use variable for storing the state. For example if you have several targets.

```
     var childrenState = {};
        function open() {
            childrenState[id] = true;
        }

for (var i in childrenState) {
    if (childrenState[i]) {
       showText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.

```
 $('#container >div').each(function(){ 
          if($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
              //hide text
            }
            else
            {
              //show text
            }
     });
```

Comment: Gives me: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried your code. Didn't work for me unfortunately. The last command it got was to `hide`, while one div was shown in the hidden panel.

Comment: can you please provide your div structure?